# Creating objects of different Types using a unified Signature

Tags: c#, serialization, interface, constraints, factory

Imagine the following two classes:

```
class A
{
    public A()
    {
    }
}
class B : A
{
    public B()
    {
    }
}
```

Is it possible for me to define A, or alternatively an interface, in a way that forces class B to have a parameterless constructor? Or, more generalized, a constructor (or static method) that is able to create an instance of type B with a given signature?

I do *not* want to restrict class B to only be constructible using that signature, but I want to be sure that class B *can* be constructed with this signature (be it parameterless, or specifying certain parameters).

To be clear: I am not searching for a solution that would require me to use Reflection or any other method to figure that out at runtime (I don't have a problem with it, but it would make the code less readable, and generally seems like a bad idea in this case).

Is there a way to accomplish this?

I wrote a blog post that goes more in-depth about what I am trying to achieve [here](http://xyuwelion.blogspot.de/2013/09/my-first-blog-post-arrives-huh-i-am.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is no interface or base type that you can apply to the type to ensure it has a parameterless constructor.  The only context in which you can make such a contraint is generic constraints:

```
public static void Foo<T>()
    where T : new() {}
```

In such a case the only types that can be used with `Foo` must have a parameterless constructor.

Comment: Is this also usable if I want to enforce that the object have, say, always a constructor that takes one argument of type List<int>? Or any other number and combination of arguments I would want? And if the constructor is not possible, maybe enforce that the class has a static method constructing an instance of itself (of course also being able to force certain parameters to be taken by that method)? If not, it is not usable for my case, still thanks for the quick reply :)

Comment: @user2791287 That is not possible, no.

Comment: Edited the initial question with a link to what I am trying to do, maybe this gives a more precise idea about what I want to do, and maybe there are alternatives I have overlooked o:

Comment: @user2791287 It's simply not possible, given the constraints on the problem you've given.  If it weren't such a hard problem to solve, there would be solutions out there already.  The reason that the existing solutions have problems is due to the inherent problems and limitations in trying to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can define factory for instantiating objects of type `A` (and derived types):

```
interface IFactory<T> where T : A
{
    T Create(int i);
    T Create(string s);
    // and so on...
}
```

and require factory implementation, when you want to create an object.
This will make sure calling code in compile time, that it tries to create an object with the given set of parameters.

Of course, there's nothing preventing from `NotImplementedException` from concrete `IFactory<T>` implementation at run-time.

Comment: I thought about this, but it does not really work, since even the factory has to assume that the object it instantiates just supports a certain way of constructing it. I cannot use the factory to enforce that I can construct an object this way. Another reason I don't want to do this, is, that the classes I am trying to constrain are compiled at runtime, meaning I would essentially force every scripted class to also implement a factory. And even then, I cannot force the script to allow me to create the factory in a certain way...

Answer (score 0):

This is a followup, since I did a little bit of research and at least managed to come up with an answer that is somewhat satisfying.

So after digging around a while and trying to figure out how the built-in serialization/deserialization in C# works, I found out that C# has a method called `GetUninitializedObject()`. This method seems like a hack, since it just avoids calling the constructor of the object in the first place, but it at least gives me a way to accomplish what I originally wanted: Being able to deserialize an object of an arbitrary type. Using this, I am able to use methods on the uninitialized created objects (and forcing their implementation via an interface).

I find this to be fitting my needs, although it does not do what I originally wanted to, it allows me to implement a pattern that works for my purposes.

Best Regards